# Maven multi modules tomcat deployment , module missing

Tags: java, maven, tomcat, jar, war

I have two module in parent pom. A project depends on B project. I followed [here](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/MAVENUSER/Multi-modules+projects)

In A project , i added B project as dependency. Its ok in build path, I see my B project under maven dependencies.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>mygroup</groupId>
    <artifactId>B</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

But when I deploy A project into Tomcat(mvn tomcat7:deploy ,or redeploy) , A project was deployed successfully but B project(packaging as jar) wasn't deployed. (Also I tried to system scope and target the jar file with systemPath)

I didn't understand where is the issue, Did i miss something? (Using Tomcat8 , no eclipse specific answer please.)

Comment: Can you share the parent pom , B project pom annd full contents from WAR pom ? There could be multiple instances within the pom that causes the issue..

Comment: did you add the dependency into the <dependencyManagement> section only? or into <dependencies>? mvn dependency:tree on the pom.xml of project A should show the dependency - if it does not the dependency is in the wrong place? or has it a scope of some kind? like "provided" in the parent pom?

Comment: I will share 6 hours later all poms. By the way it works well with mvn -pl tomcat7:run command, but it's embedded tomcat server and not useful for me.

Comment: In parent pom i have only module definitions. My maven tomcat deploy command which is mvn tomcat7:deploy could be wrong? Do i need any other configuration in pom about tomcat?(using tomcat7-maven-plugin, in conf definitions url,path,username,password)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try mvn install and manually copy the generated war to tomcat7 folder. Maybe something is wrong with tomcat7 maven plugin.

Additional Information: In .m2 repository there wasn't project B's jar , installed it and changed tomcat7 plugin as this solution alternetive to maven war plugin and configured outputfolder tomcat8's webapps folder, now it works like a charm.